# CoreOS / etcd: how to manage my secrets?

Tags: chef-infra, coreos, etcd, consul

I'm currently trying out CoreOS.

I'm reaching the point where I need my container to have access to some secrets informations, e.g. SSL private keys, API keys, etc ...

Chef provides nice ways to deal with those secrets, the simplest being encrypted data bags. I'd like to have something similar for CoreOS.

What is the idiomatic way to manage secrets with CoreOS ?

Answers requiring additional services (e.g. consul) are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there is not a default way to crypt some keys in etcd or consul in a similar way as Chef Encrypted Data Bags. There is a project called [Crypt](http://xordataexchange.github.io/crypt/) designed to solve this problem. It has implementation for etcd and consul.

Answer (score 3):

You should most probably check out this project:

https://vaultproject.io

It's  a tool from creators of Consul/Serf/Vagrant/.. aimed for managing secrets. It run in a server mode and encrypts data before writing it to disk, there is good 'Getting started' guide on their webpage which might give a good overview whether it will work for you or not.

Vault is open source, and as yet another project written in Go language fits CoreOS environment really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that [Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) might be the best solution.

[Go implementation](https://github.com/codahale/sss) ([docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/codahale/sss))

Next is figuring out how it can all fit cleanly inside `etcd`…

Answer (score 0):

See https://coderanger.net/chef-secrets/ for a summary of the major options with managing secrets in Chef.

Comment: I know that. The question is about CoreOS and Etcd, not Chef. Still, thanks for answering :-)